# remove product from redux shopping cart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, backend

Im trying to make a shopping cart using react redux. i can add products to my shopping cart but have no idea how to remove a product from my cart.
i tried to remove by splice method but it doesnt seem to work.

Heres my cartRedux -

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {
        products:[],
        quantity:0,
        total:0
    },
    reducers:{
        addProduct: (state, action) => {
            state.quantity += 1;
            state.products.push(action.payload);
            state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
        },
        removeProduct: (state, action) => {
            let index = state.products.indexOf(action.payload);
            state.quantity -= action.payload
            state.products.splice(index, 1)
        }
    },
});

export const {addProduct} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox and share for better understanding

Comment: i can add products to my cart but i cant remove a product. If i remove a product it doesnt update the price.

Comment: Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tree-q6wyd5 
see redux folder inside src folder

Comment: hi,bro,can you share the code of UI part,I wanna to see how it succeed to add product to shopping cart.

Comment: I updated the sandbox with productDetails file which contains the addtocart function

Comment: @Bun, Of all you are mutating the state, generally it's not advisable, you should be creating a new copy of state and return in. the codesandbox you shared is not functionable, it would be great if you can modify it to make it functionable so that i can help out

Comment: hi@Bun,if code functionable could save a lot of time to debug and screen the code using redux-devtool.But if not,the standard procedure to debug is check ui component with test library first and then go for reducer mock and middleware,that means I will rebuild it.Thanks bro.But if you do not like that,just reference this part:`Nothing happens when I dispatch an action` https://redux.js.org/usage/troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Replace the array instead of its content.

Changing the line :

```
state.products.slice(index, 1)]
```

by

```
state.products.splice(index, 1)
state.products = [...state.products] // clone array
```

should allow redux to notice the change.

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt really understand you. @Baart

Comment: You reaffect the new array instead of just changing its inner values.

By doing that, the reference of the array is updated, which allows redux to know that the array has changed, and it will trigger the update.

Comment: tried that, doesnt work. it removes the all other products except for the one im trying to remove.

Comment: I updated the answer. This should now work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Receives the item ID as a payload which is then used to remove from the state using the filter method.

```
  const removeItem = state.products.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
  state.products = removeItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

removeProduct: (state, action) =>{state.products.indexOf(action.payload);
state.products.splice(action.payload, 1)};

Comment: Can you please add a description on the change that you're suggesting, and what you think is wrong in the current code ? This could help others understand better your solution. thx.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).